# Basic Auth + Rest API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, basic-authentication

I am developing a Rest Api, that will be consumed from a javascript.

So If I use basic authentication, the user and passoword (encoded in base64) will be visible on the java script running on the client browser.

How can I protect my API?  Do I have to user CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to protect it?
Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: The questions states that you seek both to protect the API and access it from browserborne Javascript, which leaves the definition of 'protect' a bit vague. Could you clarify it?

Comment: Let me clarify: my user is already authenticated in a third part site. It is a e-commerce website. We are deploying html+js page on the same server of the e-commerce website and this js will call our API. So I need to protect my API not to be called from a unauthorized user. When I say user can be the logged user or just accept call from the website domain.

Comment: I'd recommend using oAuth, this link provides some useful approaches. Implicit grant or the thin client approach suggested further below in the article should help: http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/

Also, basic authentication is often seen less secure as you need to resend the password on each request(albeit in encrypted form if you're using SSL, but nevetheless resulting in increasing the size of the attack window). Here is a link about that: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https

Comment: I think in that case you're safe, as only the user (or somebody on their browser after they've logged in, which is impossible to secure anyway) can access the javascript on the page. My only advice would be to avoid putting the credentials in localStorage/cookies, but that's probably not an issue anyway

Comment: @John Doe: But if a logged user see the js, and get basic authentication information? This basic authentication information will be shared among users. I can have a malicious user that will get the basic authentication information and retrieve information from other users using my API

Comment: True... With that in mind, I don't think basic auth is much of an option

Answer (score 0):

Notes from comment conversation:

- the webservice is authenticated from another site; is not open to just any user.

I think you'll have to individuate the authentication, which I don't think is possible/practical with basic auth. I'd recommend some sort of [freeradius](http://freeradius.org/) + OAuth, given that you have users authenticating on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

To protect an API there are different authentication based security techniques suggested by APIGEE, stormpath.

**OAuth 2.0**
**OAuth 1.0a**

You should ideally avoid basic authentication, that not one of the  best practices.